# "Card flip" a checkbox without exposing backface

Tags: css, checkbox, transform

I want to give a checkbox a 3D horizontal flip transformation on checked. I want to use standard input checkbox so no adding extra divs or spans around or inside it. I got it to work using :after psuedo elements the only problem is when I check the box the checkmark appears before the flip happens. I tried backface-visibility hidden but that results in one of the sides being invisible since it is the backface.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

css:

```
input{
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
input:after{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
   -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
   -webkit-perspective: 800;
   background:white;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   line-height:20px;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   text-align: center;
   content:"";
}
input:checked:after{
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg);
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    content:"\2713";      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrzyggkp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: just add `color:transparent` and set `content:"\2713"`on `input:after` pseudo element, no animation needed.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrzyggkp/6/

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:after {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  content: "\2713";
  color: transparent;
}

input:checked:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg);
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "\2713";
}
```

Comment: you likely don't need an animation, just a delay on the transition

Comment: Thanks! I used this to get to my final answer. I added a transition delay to exactly halfway through the transform to give it more distinct card sides: http://jsfiddle.net/od0mgu5s/